# Run SPA on a different Route

Tags: reactjs, go, kubernetes, single-page-application, gorilla

So I've set up my SPA in Go using Gorilla/Mux but I want to run it on different routes so I can connect two of my Kubernetes services together (2 different SPAs). *could it be that I have to change my kubernetes service to /stock instead?*

My one service runs on the regular path "/" and I want to add a second service so that when the user types in "https://URL/stock" my second SPA is served (want 2nd spa to run on /stock)

I know one way would just be to merge my code and whatnot into my first service, but I was wondering if I could do it this way?

**main.go**

```golang
type spaHandler struct {
    staticPath string
    indexPath  string
}

func (h spaHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path, err := filepath.Abs(r.URL.Path)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    path = filepath.Join(h.staticPath, r.URL.Path)

    _, err = os.Stat(path)
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, filepath.Join(h.staticPath, h.indexPath))
        return
    } else if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    http.FileServer(http.Dir(h.staticPath)).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}


func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    //Serve Other Routes Above PathPrefix
    router.HandleFunc("/api/findStock", findStock)
    spa := spaHandler{staticPath: "./stock/build", indexPath: "index.html"}
    router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(spa) <------ any way to serve on /stock???

    svr := &http.Server{
        Handler: router,
        Addr:    ":8080",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    log.Fatal(svr.ListenAndServe())
}
```

**App.js**

```js
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <section>
              <NavBar/>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/'  component={Home}/>
              </Switch>
            </section>
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I know I can change the path to /stock in App.js but when I got to localhost:8080/ it still shows my navbar on it

**UPDATED**

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
   - host: www.url.com
     http:
       paths:
         - backend:
             serviceName: service1
             servicePort: 80
           path: /
         - backend:
             serviceName: stockService
             servicePort: 80
           path: /stock
```

So when I go to the /stock endpoint, I'm getting

The resource from "www.url.com//static/css/2.d9ad5f5c.chunk.css" was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

I assume this is because my Stock Service default path is set to / in main.go so it's trying to serve files from there, but on the web I'm trying to access it from /stock

**NEW UPDATE/FIX**

**main.go**

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    //Serve Other Routes Above PathPrefix
    router.HandleFunc("/api/findStock", findStock)
    spa := spaHandler{staticPath: "./stock/build", indexPath: "index.html"}
    router.PathPrefix("/stock").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/stock", spa)) <-- UPDATED

    svr := &http.Server{
        Handler:      router,
        Addr:         ":8080",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    log.Fatal(svr.ListenAndServe())
}
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <section>
              <NavBar/>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/stock'  component={Home}/>
              </Switch>
            </section>
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "homepage": "stock", <---- This was newly added to the top of my file
  "name": "stock",
  "version": "0.1.0",
}
```

I'm still using ingress to access my second service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually found a different fix myself after doing a lot of research. I was running into trouble using Name Based Virtual hosting/ having two different ingress classes.

I decided to modify my react app root directory (didn't know I could do that before)

**package.json**

```
{
"homepage": "stock",
}
```

I also served my Home component in my **App.js** from `/stock`

and the changed my **main.go**

```
router.PathPrefix("/stock").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/stock", spa))
```

Updated code will be changed above

Answer (score 2):

Although doable, if you are using Kubernetes it seems hacky to do it the way you are doing it. Why not use 2 [Kubernetes services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and then connect to them through an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) controller like [Nginx](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)? For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /stock
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: stock-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: first-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

✌️

Comment: So I tested out what you told me todo. I added a nginx controller. Got everything up and running. Only thing is that currently that apiVersion is not supported so I had to use "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1" and I couldn't put pathType with it. I also can't access /stock. Only shows a blank page

Comment: Yoo need to remove the ` nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` annotation if your stock app is serving under `/stock` Updated the answer

Comment: I can't serve my SPA from /stock in my main.go and removing rewrite-target still gives me the same issue

Comment: where are you serving your stock app? from `/`? what about the other SPA? Please clarify where you want to serve each one.

Comment: so both my SPA look exactly like my main.go file above. My main service is running on `/`  and i want my stock app to run on `/stock` Currently my stock app is serving from `/` but I can't seem to change the path prefix to work on `/stock`

Comment: It's better to use either Name Based Virtual hosting for each SPA: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting . Or use two different ingress classes https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class -- Two different instances of the ingress controller with a different ingress class each.

Comment: This is because you want to serve both of your applications under `/`